# Zend Form Display Group Decorators

Tags: zend-framework, zend-form, decorator

I am trying to figure our how to remove the label from a display group, when you look at the 
markup below you will see that there is a dt with the id address-label and the following dd, I want to remove these but keep 
the fieldset.

To add the display group I am using this `$this->addDisplayGroup(array(...), 'legend' => 'address');` within
my form init class after I have added each of the elements. Are there some decorators I can play with to remove
the element I dont want?

```
<form id="CreateAddress" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded" action="" method="post">
    <dl class="zend_form"> 
        <dt id="address-label">&#160;</dt>
        <dd id="address-element">
            <fieldset id="fieldset-address">
                <legend>Address</legend> 
                <dl>             
                    <dt id="addressLine1-label">
                        <label for="addressLine1" class="required">Address Line 1</label>
                    </dt> 
                    <dd id="addressLine1-element"> 
                        <input type="text" name="addressLine1" id="addressLine1" value="">
                    </dd> 

                    ...etc...

            </fieldset>
        </dd> 
        ...buttons...
    </dl>
</form>
```

Thanks,
Martin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So what's the deal?

```
$group = $form->getDisplayGroup ('the name of the group');
$group->removeDecorator ('Zend_Form_Decorator_DtDdWrapper');
```

Answer (score 8):

If you want to apply it to all Zend Form Display Groups defined (for a particular form), a neater way is:

```
$form->setDisplayGroupDecorators(array(
    'FormElements',
    'Fieldset',
));
```

NOTE: this only alters previously defined Display Groups.

Answer (score 5):

The `removeDecorator` parameter `Zend_Form_Decorator_DtDdWrapper` didn't work so I used:

```
$group = $form->getDisplayGroup('the name of the group');
$group->removeDecorator('DtDdWrapper');
```

Answer (score 1):

So that you don't have to manually remove the DtDd's from each display group individually, you can use:

```
foreach ($this->_displayGroups as $dg){
            $dg->removeDecorator('DtDdWrapper');
        }
```